# ¿Como importar componente primeng en varios module Angular?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular-datatables

Saludos comunidad, estoy tratando de importar componentes de primeng en dos módulos diferentes y me sale error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors

y en general cuando importo un componente que se encuentra en otro module también sale ese error, como puedo solucionarlo?

**Parameter.module.ts**

```
// Ng
import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DataTableModule, // <= Componente
    SharedModule, // <= Componente
    ParameterRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    ParamComponent,
    ParametersComponent,
    ParametersSysytemComponent
  ]
})
```

**User.module.ts**

```
import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {CalendarModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {MultiSelectModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DataTableModule, // <= Componente
    SharedModule, // <= Componente
    CalendarModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    TreeModule,
    CaptchaModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    HomeRouting
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    DefaultComponent,
    IframeComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    EditUserComponent,
    ModalsComponent,
    UserTestComponent,
    SaveUserComponent,
    DeleteUserComponent,
    PasswordComponent,
    ProfilesComponent,
    NewProfile,
    ProfileEditComponent,
    RolesComponent
  ]
})
```

Comment: Es el típico error al no importar el modulo en el sitio adecuado. Puedes postear el componente que da el error ademas de el error completo?

Comment: Hola amigo. ya logre solucionarlo, Gracias!!